# Animating Opacity of an image using mouseover and mouseleave events

Tags: jquery

I have 2 images inside a  with opacity set to 0.2 :

When I hover over the div, I want to bring the opacity to 1 for the 2 images, here is the code :

```
$(".comment-thread").live("mouseover", function () {


    $(this).find('.comment-rating-down').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
    $(this).find('.comment-rating-up').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
```

});

$(".comment-thread").live("mouseout", function () {

```
    $(this).find('.comment-rating-down').animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 500);
    $(this).find('.comment-rating-up').animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 500);
```

});

What happens is when I hover over the div, the 2 buttons blinks like 4 times and more as if it is buffering the animation.

Is there a better technique ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "mouseenter" "mouseleave" events instead, the mouseover and mouseout fire multiple times.

Also chain the animation to the .stop function

> $(this).find('.comment-rating-down').stop(true,true).animate({
>   opacity: 1 }, 500); 
>   $(this).find('.comment-rating-up').stop(true,true).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);

the .stop function helps in preventing multiple animations from queuing up, for example if you mouseover/out of the images really fast multiple times, you will get animations that continue on for awhile.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

What about .hover() ?

```
$(".comment-thread").hover(function(){
  var t = $(this);
  t.find('.comment-rating-down').stop().animate({opacity: 1 }, 500);
  t.find('.comment-rating-up').stop().animate({opacity: 1 }, 500);
},function(){
  var t = $(this);
  t.find('.comment-rating-down').stop().animate({opacity: 0.2 }, 500);
  t.find('.comment-rating-up').stop().animate({opacity: 0.2 }, 500);
});
```